# WooCommerce - Remove cart?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

I want to take a straight payment for the one item, not have multiple items and cart functionality.

This is what I have so far:

User views product, presses buy and goes to checkout (via a straight checkout link), problem is here is that at the top of the checkout page it says “XXXX product has been added to cart – View Cart”. I don’t want this cart part there it should just go straight to the checkout and take the payment.

Another problem is if they go back through my funnel it adds a second item into the cart. I only want them to be able to purchase a quantity of 1 so I don't need any cart functionality just a straight checkout.

How can this be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code redirect users to Checkout Page after add to cart.

```
/**
 * Redirect users to Checkout Page after add to cart.
 */
function my_custom_add_to_cart_redirect( $url ) {
    $url = WC()->cart->get_checkout_url();
    return $url;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'my_custom_add_to_cart_redirect' );
```

You can also try this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-direct-checkout/

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. I actually have a button with the url set to mywebsite.com/checkout/?id=99 which sends the page straight to the checkout. The problem is that at the top of the checkout it says "X item has been added to the cart - View Cart" and also if they same user goes back through the funnel it then adds 2 items into the cart. I don't want the cart at all, I already go straight to the checkout but don't want that cart message at the top and only want to allow one item?